# Question about meaning of "coherent whole" in this passage

Tags: sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

> Among the believers and the wider society, the bounty of being able to turn to a Local Spiritual Assembly for guidance and for the resolution of difficult situations is being recognized, and in turn, the decisions of the Spiritual Assemblies are increasingly characterized by wisdom and sensitivity. There is much here to indicate that, **when the elements of the Plan’s framework for action are combined into a coherent whole, the impact on a population can be profound** . And it is against the background of ongoing expansion and consolidation—the thirtieth cycle of the intensive programme of growth has recently concluded—that the friends are actively exploring, with the rest of the island’s inhabitants, what it means for a Mashriqu’l-Adhkár, a “collective centre for men’s souls”, to be raised up in their midst. With the active support of traditional leaders, Tanna islanders have offered no less than a hundred design ideas for the Temple, demonstrating the extent to which the House of Worship has captured imaginations, and opening up enthralling prospects for the influence it is set to exert on the lives lived beneath its shade.

In this part it is difficult to understand what it means in terms of language. I cannot understan the word so I cannot get the gist of the highlighted part. 
Could you please define the **coherent whole** in simple English and if possible paraphrase the highlighted part in simple English. Thank you a million time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"when the elements ... are combined into a coherent whole" is really the important part for understanding what "coherent whole" means. An analogy would be puzzle pieces, that when put together correctly form a picture.

So there is a "Plan's framework for action" which has some "elements", presumably particular actions or policies. When these elements are combined in such a way that they support each other or work toward a common goal and thus are a "coherent whole" greater than the separate elements, "the impact on the population can be profound".

Answer (score 0):

"Coherent" means "sticking together", i.e. all parts (of the framework for action ) are in aid of the same goal and make sense *together*. If someone is "incoherent", he or she is babbling disjointedly and does not make sense.